# Magento how to show bundle product tier price in listing page

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I would like to show tier price of bundle product in product listing/category listing page.Is it possible to show it on listing page? I try hard but can't find solution.

Answer (score 2):

In theory this should work.

```
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml($_product) ?>
```

But it seams there is an issue that wasn't fixed until now.
A possible workaround could be this:

```
<?php $this->setProduct(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($_product->getId()))?>
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
<?php $this->unsProduct($_product); // don't leave unnecessary data?>
```

Even if this works, I'm not sure it's a good idea to load the product in a loop (performance).
To overcome this, I think you can set the attribute tier_price to be Used in Product Listing and then you should be able to skip the load part and use only:

```
<?php $this->setProduct($_product)?>
<?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
<?php $this->unsProduct($_product); // don't leave unnecessary data?>
```

But I haven't tested it.

It might help.